# Mostrar Imagem em ImageView

Tags: android

Tenho uma projeto que uso Fragments, tenho um botão o qual me direciona para a galeria de imagens, ali tenho que selecionar uma imagem e mostra em um image view, porem não estou conseguindo.

```
btnGaleria.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);

        }



    });


  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (requestCode == IMAGEM_INTERNA) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGEM_INTERNA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri imagemSelecionada = intent.getData();

            String[] colunas = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(imagemSelecionada, colunas, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int indexColuna = cursor.getColumnIndex(colunas[0]);
            String pathimg = cursor.getString(indexColuna);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathimg);
            this.image_selecionada.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Imagem não existe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Se for se basear pelo que vc postou aqui do código ta osso, bro, veja bem, começa por voce verificar duas veses por "requestCode" em `if (requestCode == IMAGEM_INTERNA)` e depois dentro desse `if` voce verifica novamente pelo mesmo, depois, para voce usar esse valor contido em "IMAGEN_INTERNA" no método `public void onActivityResult(...) {...}` voce tem obrigatoriamente de passar esse valor pela chamada do intent e pelo que pude ver voce passa 0 pelo seu Intent.
verifica isso ai e treina mais cara

Answer (score 0):

Para acessar a galeria do celular é usada uma **Intent** padrão do android:

```
Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, CONSTANTE_ESCOLHIDO);
```

Assim você receberá no `onActivityResult()` a imagem escolhida em forma de **Uri**:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data != null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == CONSTANTE_ESCOLHIDO) {  
        Uri photoData = data.getData();      
    }
}
```

Assim você pode transformar esse **Uri** em um **Bitmap** e coloca-lo em uma ImageView:

```
photoBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), photoData);
photoView.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap);
```